# XMPP (Jabber) windows client with SSO features

Tags: windows, client, xmpp, single-sign-on

I'k looking for a xmpp windows client with SSO feature in a Windows Domain.
I've tried pandion but it doens't work.

Comment: Not sure if this question wouldn't be more adequate at serverfault or superuser.

Comment: google chat OK? https://www.pingidentity.com/our-solutions/google-apps.cfm

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/57159/google-apps-ad-and-sso

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking for [Kerberos 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) support.  The [GSSAPI SASL mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4752) is how this works on the wire.  I think [Psi](http://psi-im.org/) implements `GSSAPI`.  Setting this up on the server side can be *hard*, so please don't assume that if it doesn't work the first time it is the client's fault.

Comment: Pidgin also supports GSSAPI I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Spark + Openfire (http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1362)